# NSTableView row mask

Tags: ios, ios6, uiimage, nstableview

I have a 69x69 UIImage in a table view row that is 69 high. I want the UIImage to abut the top, left, and bottom of the row, but can't quite figure it out since in each section of the table the first and last rows have rounded corners. If I put the image right up against the edge, it looks fine in the middle rows, but it goes over the rounded edge of the first and last rows. Is there a simple setting in Storyboard to use the table cell as a mask over the UIImage or as a boundary for the UIImage? Or do I have to programmatically mask the UIImage depending on which cell it is in?

Thanks!

Comment: you might find your answer [in here](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html). I am not totally sure what you are asking, what type of cells you have, or how you are creating it, but check that out.

Comment: A bit of confusion here - the title (and tags) mention NSTableView (which is OS X), but the rest of the question talks about UIImage (iOS). Did you mean UITableView?